# How do I find the differences between two git remotes

Tags: git, git-svn

In my local copy of our svn repo (created using git-svn), I have multiple remotes representing a series of releases of our project: remotes/tags/release1 remotes/tags/release2 etc. How can I use git to show me the changed revisions and/or the diffs between releaseN and releaseN-1?

I have tried `git diff remotes/tags/releaseN-1 remotes/tags/releaseN`  and `git log remotes/tags/releaseN-1 remotes/tags/releaseN`, but both of these just give me the "unknown revision or path not in the working tree" error message.

Comment: Are you sure that you use `remotes/tags/*`?  It is not the default... Check `git for-each-ref` output if tags are where you think they are. BTW. have you tried using `refs/remotes/tags/releaseN-1` etc.?

Comment: I think you may be confusing remotes and tags. Add the output of `ls -R .git/refs` to the question (or put it somewhere like pastebin if it's overly long)

Comment: That's correct, remotes/tags/* is not standard. That's the way my repo is configured. It actually maps from ^/releases/* on the SVN server... which doesn't precisely make sense. I didn't set it up :-)